# Couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request - Microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, metrics-server

Previously I had Microk8s cluster which was on Kubernetes 1.24 version. Recently I have upgraded the Kubernetes version to 1.26. And also, I'm using Metrics-server through Microk8s addons. In the earlier K8s version i didn't get the below error but after the upgrade it appears. The functionlity of the metrics server contains no issues. But need to get rid of the warnings during the installation.

> **E0629 08:41:59.515719 1850142 memcache.go:287] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request**

Anyone has an idea on this?

I tried to install the metrics server using Microk8s addons on Kubernetes 1.26 without those warnings.

Comment: did you fixed this issue?